# Share modules between two Angular 2 Apps

Tags: angular, ag-grid-ng2

My project consists of two seperate Angular Apps that have to share a module. 
It's working perfectly in App A but when I create a relative import from App B to A it throws a `StaticInjectorError`.

```
ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[AgGridNg2 -> ComponentFactoryResolver]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[AgGridNg2 -> ComponentFactoryResolver]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for ComponentFactoryResolver!
```

I was hoping to just change the import path in App B so that it points to the module in App A.

Like this:
App A (This works just fine):

```
import { GridModule } from './grid/grid.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    GridModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

App B:

```
import { GridModule } from '../../../qtgridview/src/app/grid/grid.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    GridModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

The module in question:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    AgGridModule.withComponents([
      IconCellRendererComponent
    ])
  ],
  providers: [],
  declarations: [GridComponent, IconCellRendererComponent],
  exports: [GridComponent]
})
export class GridModule { }
```

Ist this possible? How would I go about including a module in such a way? Thanks in advance

Comment: make that Grid Module as npm package and use it as package in any number of angular apps

Comment: please check this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42041156/angular-2-sharing-a-module-between-different-ng2-apps